# Can I assign offsetHeight to style.top?

Tags: javascript, css

In javascript, can I assign like this:

```
var tempHeight = document.getElementById("header").offsetHeight;
document.getElementById("content").style.top = tempHeight;
```

After running above script, will the div "content" have "top" propery = tempHeight?
I tried but it does not work, any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a unit

```
document.getElementById("content").style.top = String(tempHeight) + "px";
```

Comment: thank you so much, I'm new to Javascript, I tried something link tempHeight.toString but it didn't work. Thanks your for String() function :D

Comment: A `Number` is automatically converted to a `String` when concatonated with a `String`. So, casting `String` is unnecessary.

Comment: `console.log(typeof tempHeight) // number`
`console.log(typeof (tempHeight + 'px')) // string`

Comment: @Trevor You're right - it's just an old habit of mine to always explicitly cast to string. But you're right that it's completely unnecessary in this case

Answer (score 0):

The `top` CSS property expects a unit along with the value. Adding `px` should work:

```
document.getElementById("content").style.top = tempHeight + "px";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `+ 'px'` or some unit to the end of the `style.top` statement.

Also, `#content` must have the `position` style set

http://jsfiddle.net/BshuC/

CSS

```
 #header {
        height: 200px;
 }
 #content { position: absolute; }
```

JS

```
var tempHeight = document.getElementById("header").offsetHeight;
document.getElementById("content").style.top = tempHeight + 'px';
```